# issues with adding anchor tag around the image tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have my Flex Gallery working well, only issue is when I add an `<a>` tag to the around `<img>` tag and it all messes up.

When I wrap the `<img>` tag around with an `<a>` tag so I can open the full size images, it ends up messing the whole design, I am sure something in my CSS is messing it up, how can fix it

```css
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
section,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  max-width: 76.5rem;
  padding: clamp(0.5rem, 2vw, 2rem);
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.gallery>div {
  columns: 16em;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Gallery Title Here</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/OyCl7Y4y0Bk" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Kl1gC0ve620" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/55btQzyDiO8" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g0dBbrGmMe0" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/v1OW17UcR-Q" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Wpg3Qm0zaGk" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/W3FC_bCPw8E" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rBRZLPVLQg0" alt="">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RRksEVVoU8o" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So you want to turn your images into clickable links. am I right?

Comment: yes, right, and i wrapped around it with a tag but it messed up the whole gallery

Comment: Could you share the "messed up" code snippets and possibly a jsfiddle?
By the sounds of things it's because you have the css applied to .gallery img, and when you're using the anchor tag around the image the styling isn't applied to the anchor, so you should pretty much just rename ".gallery img" to ".gallery a"

Comment: I agree with Seann I also think that you can replace  image html codes by only <a> tags with different classes Like <a class="a1"></a>,.. and then set their background images in CSS

Comment: i think i tried already said by @seann and it really messesup the design

Comment: See this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vxnw32ez/) it seems to be fine with the anchor tags, the design appears the exact same as without them

Comment: for me, when i add the anchor, instead of displaying 3 in a row, it just ends showing two in a row

Comment: @moorad when I resize it shows 3.. It looks perfect to me

Comment: Agree with the other posters above, but a functioning example of the broken state will be helpful here, for future readers if nothing else.

Comment: @Jake I don't think he means broken. When I open the picture from link, the image is scaled up too much in the destination link. so we need styling in the destination link which will need some Javascript or he can make separate styled image html pages and then link them to the main html

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. The anchor tags make zero difference.

```css
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
section,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  max-width: 76.5rem;
  padding: clamp(0.5rem, 2vw, 2rem);
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.gallery>div {
  columns: 16em;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Gallery With Links</h2>
  <div>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/OyCl7Y4y0Bk"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Kl1gC0ve620"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/55btQzyDiO8"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g0dBbrGmMe0"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/v1OW17UcR-Q"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Wpg3Qm0zaGk"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/W3FC_bCPw8E"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rBRZLPVLQg0"></a>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RRksEVVoU8o"></a>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Gallery Without Links</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/OyCl7Y4y0Bk">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Kl1gC0ve620">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/55btQzyDiO8">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g0dBbrGmMe0">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/v1OW17UcR-Q">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Wpg3Qm0zaGk">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/W3FC_bCPw8E">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rBRZLPVLQg0">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RRksEVVoU8o">
  </div>
</section>
```